# Spark Scala Dataframe convert a column of Array of Struct to a column of Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Scala.
 I have a Dataframe with fields

```
ID:string, Time:timestamp, Items:array(struct(name:string,ranking:long))
```

I want to convert each row of the *Items* field to a hashmap, with the *name* as the key.
I am not very sure how to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using a UDF:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

// Sample data:
val df = Seq(
  ("id1", "t1", Array(("n1", 4L), ("n2", 5L))),
  ("id2", "t2", Array(("n3", 6L), ("n4", 7L)))
).toDF("ID", "Time", "Items")

// Create UDF converting array of (String, Long) structs to Map[String, Long]
val arrayToMap = udf[Map[String, Long], Seq[Row]] {
  array => array.map { case Row(key: String, value: Long) => (key, value) }.toMap
}

// apply UDF
val result = df.withColumn("Items", arrayToMap($"Items"))

result.show(false)
// +---+----+---------------------+
// |ID |Time|Items                |
// +---+----+---------------------+
// |id1|t1  |Map(n1 -> 4, n2 -> 5)|
// |id2|t2  |Map(n3 -> 6, n4 -> 7)|
// +---+----+---------------------+
```

I can't see a way to do this without a UDF (using Spark's built-in functions only).

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.4.0, one can use [`map_from_entries`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#map_from_entries-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-):

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (Array(("n1", 4L), ("n2", 5L))),
  (Array(("n3", 6L), ("n4", 7L)))
).toDF("Items")

df.select(map_from_entries($"Items")).show

/*
+-----------------------+
|map_from_entries(Items)|
+-----------------------+
|     [n1 -> 4, n2 -> 5]|
|     [n3 -> 6, n4 -> 7]|
+-----------------------+
*/
```